# Ionic / angular directive bind to scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this scrolling div:

```
<div class="list">
  <div class="item" ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <img src="post.img" is-visible/>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this in a directive:

```
angular.element(window).on('DOMContentLoaded load resize scroll', function () {
  console.log("window change");
});
```

The goal is to detect scroll.  The problem is that only `load` and `resize` are triggering the console comment. Scrolling up and down the list does not trigger it. Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are scrolling to particular `div` which has `ng-repeat` directive, & you had applied scroll on `window`. Which would not get fire until you get scroll to window.

Ideally you should set scroll event to particular which would wrapper on `ng-repeat` element. So that can act as scroll bar container for `posts` collection.

**Markup**

```
<div is-visible id="post-list" class="list" style="overflow-y:scroll;width: 400px;height: 120px;border: 1px solid gray;">
  <div id="post-{{$index}}" class="item card" ng-repeat="post in posts">
    Message: {{post.message}}
  </div>
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
.directive('isVisible', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.on('scroll', function(){
           console.log('Scroll has been detected.');
        })
      }
    }
})
```

[**Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/BzbmLI92gOS0RizBAdJF?p=preview)

Comment: do you mean `on('resize'`  or `on('scroll'`  ?

Comment: @lilbiscuit thanks for heads up..mistaken while doing copy and paste.. I wrote console.log message correctly, but missed that event name part :D Tysm :-)

Comment: @lilbiscuit were you able to succeed in creation of sample codepen/plunkr?

Comment: @lilbiscuit Glad to help you. Thanks :). :p

Answer (score 0):

The HTML is embedded in a `<ion-content></ion-content>` block and that's what's scrolling... so that's what I need to bind to:

HTML

```
<ion-content id="my-content">
  <div is-visible id="post-list" class="list" style="overflow-y:scroll;width:   400px;height: 120px;border: 1px solid gray;">
    <div id="post-{{$index}}" class="item card" ng-repeat="post in posts">
      Message: {{post.message}}
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

DIRECTIVE

```
.directive('isVisible', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var parent = angular.element(document.querySelector('#my-content'));
        parent.on('scroll', function(){
           console.log('Scroll has been detected.');
        })
      }
    }
})
```

Comment: may I know why you put scroll on `ion-content`? I think considering container to immediate child would be more accurate..like I did.. did you get time to check that?